# Formulating both general and specific stub-methods?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, rhino-mocks

in order to test another class, I want to create a stub for an interface *IFoo*:

```
public interface IFoo
{
    int DoSomething(int value);
}
```

The stub is created in the *SetUp* (or *TestInitialize*)-method for the test fixture and stored in a property as almost all test methods need an *IFoo*:

```
this.Foo = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IFoo>();
```

As IFoo.DoSomething needs just to return the passed value in all cases except one I added this behavior to my *SetUp* method:

```
this.Foo.Stub(f => f.DoSomething(0)).IgnoreArguments().Return(0).WhenCalled(mi => mi.ReturnValue = mi.Arguments[0]);
```

Now, however, this **one** test requires different behavior: Rather than returning the passed argument, a constant should be returned if the passed value equals another constant. The following approach (written in the test method itself) does **not** work:

```
this.Foo.Stub(f => f.DoSomething(42)).Return(43);
```

The previous specified, more general stub seems to override the more specific stub.
Is there any way to specify both specific and general stubs on RhinoMock-objects?

One workaround would be recreating the stub in the test-method itself - a duplication I would like to avoid. I could live with this version, however.
What I also do not want is a explicit exclusion of the "42" in the general statement via Constraints as this will effect the other tests negatively.
Calling *BackToRecord* is also not an option as it seems to reset other stubs, too.

Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the solution to actually "override" stubs / expectations: 
[Rhino Mocks: How to clear previous expectations on an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/770013/rhino-mocks-how-to-clear-previous-expectations-on-an-object/770083#770083)

Applied to my problem I can now write:

```
this.Foo.Stub(f => f.DoSomething(42)).Return(43).Repeat.Any();
```

The documentation to Any says:

> Repeat the method any number of times. This has special affects in that this method would now ignore orderring.

So this seems to be neither a bug or an undocumented feature.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think its possible to "reset" expectations. In this case I would avoid setting up this mock in the set up, instead I would create a method to easily set it up and call it from every test:

```
private IFoo SetUpFoo()
{
  IFoo foo = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IFoo>();
  foo.Stub(f => f.DoSomething(0)).IgnoreArguments().Return(0).WhenCalled(mi => mi.ReturnValue = mi.Arguments[0]);
}
```

Then just use this method in every test that needs the standard foo:

```
[Test]
public void StandardTest()
{
  IFoo foo = SetUpFoo();
  ...
}
```

in your special case you have to create foo manually and set up the expectation:

```
[Test]
public void SpecialTest()
{
  IFoo foo = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IFoo>();
  foo.Stub(f => f.DoSomething(42)).Return(43);
  ...
}
```

Of course you get some code duplication, but at least its clear which expectations are used in which test.

Comment: Well - that's very similar to what I meant with "One workaround would be recreating the stub in the test-method itself". I only wondered whether you can realize this without workarounds like those. It seems like RhinoMocks does not provide a mechanism like that.