# Stubbing a property twice with rhino mocks

Tags: c#, mocking, rhino-mocks

For some objects I want to create default stubs so that common properties contains values. But in some cases I want to override my default behaviour. My question is, can I somehow overwrite an already stubbed value?

```
//First I create the default stub with a default value
var foo = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IFoo>();
foo.Stub(x => x.TheValue).Return(1);

//Somewhere else in the code I override the stubbed value
foo.Stub(x => x.TheValue).Return(2);

Assert.AreEqual(2, foo.TheValue); //Fails, since TheValue is 1
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/770013/rhino-mocks-how-to-clear-previous-expectations-on-an-object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `Expect` instead of `Stub` and `GenerateMock` instead of `GenerateStub` will solve this:

```
//First I create the default stub with a default value
var foo = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IFoo>();
foo.Expect(x => x.TheValue).Return(1);

//Somewhere else in the code I override the stubbed value
foo.Expect(x => x.TheValue).Return(2);

Assert.AreEqual(1, foo.TheValue);
Assert.AreEqual(2, foo.TheValue);
```

Comment: Doesn't work for methods (at least in my case where i use `Arg<T>` as parameters).

Comment: Maybe you could create a new question stating your specific problem?

Comment: I thought the questioner wanted to set a number of values to default, then for each test change one of these values. I.e. not queuing up a new value, but changing it.