# Rhino mocks stub vs expect, always choosing first one why?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, rhino-mocks

I went with this solution:

[Stubbing a property twice with rhino mocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7171500/stubbing-a-property-twice-with-rhino-mocks)

but even when I change both of my Stubs to .Expect, the first Expect is winning out:

Here's the recreation in mono:

```
using System;
```

using NUnit.Framework;
using Rhino.Mocks;

namespace FirstMonoClassLibrary
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class TestingRhinoMocks
    {
        Sut _systemUnderTest;
        IFoo _dependency;

```
    [SetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        _dependency = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IFoo>();
        _dependency.Expect(x => x.GetValue()).Return(1);
        _systemUnderTest = new Sut(_dependency);
    }

    [Test]
    public void Test()
    {
        _dependency.Stub(x => x.GetValue()).Return(2);
        var value = _systemUnderTest.GetValueFromDependency();
        Assert.AreEqual(2, value);  // Fails  says it's 1
    }   
}

public interface IFoo
{
    int GetValue();
}

public class Sut
{
    private readonly IFoo _foo;

    public Sut(IFoo foo)
    {
        _foo = foo;
    }   

    public int GetValueFromDependency()
    {
        return _foo.GetValue();
    }

}
```

}

Comment: One option would be to create another TestFixture with a different Setup; another would be to create a parameterized factory method for the SUT; a third would be to avoid setting expectations in Setup. I ran into similar issues in the past and switched to [Moq](http://code.google.com/p/moq/). :)

Comment: How do you know your test/sut isn't wrong?  What does ` _dependency.GetValue` give you?  Test that to see if your mock is behaving properly.

Comment: Here's recreating it in Mono (only have my mac at the moment), and it still fails.  Wondering in the other thread I posted why that was seen as a solution when it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to do the following:

```
[Test]
public void Test()
{
   _dependency.BackToRecord();
   _dependency.Expect(_ => _.GetValue).Return(2);
   _dependency.Replay();
   var value = _systemUnderTest.GetValueFromDependency();
   value.ShouldBe(2);   // Fails  says it's 1
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I had thought that the Record, back to record, replay were deprecated uses of the library.

Comment: I would say that Expect() is also deprecated :) Personally I use only Stub() and AssertWasCalled().

Comment: Ok, so in that case how do you deal with needing to re-Stub() a different behavior?  Do you just treat that as another testfixture?

Comment: btw, I too only rely on AssertWas/WasNotCalled() and Stub().  Only issue I've had is this, trying to stub out different behavior for a different test.

Comment: You may want to look at NSubstitute -- it has better syntax and easily re-stubs your substitute by just calling Returns() method again. See http://nsubstitute.github.com/help/replacing-return-values/ for details