# RhinoMocks creates same Mock, with stored expectations, from one test to the next

Tags: unit-testing, rhino-mocks

We have a test scenario in which we have a base class that news up an instance of all Injectible dependencies for each test (in the [SetUp] method).  However, no matter what I do, stubs or expectations set in one test are being retained in subsequent tests.  Just running the following twice, I see that when I call

```
_someStub = MockRepository.GenerateMock<T>();
```

each time, the same instance is returned, even if I set it to null first, and even if I use a new instance of MockRepository like so:

```
repo = new MockRepository();
_someMock = repo.Mock<T>();
_someMock.Stub(t => t.SomeMethod()).Return(someObject);
```

I have tried doing:

```
_someMock.BackToRecord();
_someMock.Replay();
_someMock.Stub(t => t.SomeMethod()).Return(someOtherObject);
```

but for the second test, SomeMethod always returns someObject instead of someOtherObject.

I hope this makes sense.  Simplified sample code below.

```
public MockTestBase  {
     protected ISomeClass _someMock;

     [SetUp]
     protected void DoSetup() {
          _someMock = null; //just trying this, makes no difference
          _someMock = MockRepository.GenerateStub<ISomeClass>(); //returns Castle.Proxies.ISomeClassxxxxxxxxxxx every time
     } 
}

public ControllerTest : MockTestBase {
    protected MyController GetController() {
         return new MyController(_someMock );
     } 

     [Test]
     public void TestOne() {
          var object = new SomeObject() { SomeProperty = "1" };
          _someMock.Stub(t => SomeMethod()).Return(object);
          //execute test
     }

     [Test]
     public void TestTwo() {
          var object = new SomeObject() { SomeProperty = "2" };
          _someMock.Stub(t => SomeMethod()).Return(object);  
          //execute test
          //SomeMethod() returns object from TestOne
     }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/770013 - Does this help? Where is the GetController() method invoked from ? Are you reusing the same instance across tests ?

Comment: @Gishu - I have tried most of those things, but I will try Repeat.Any().  GetController is in a base class and each test calls it to get a new instance of the controller (not a reused instance).  It just feels to me like this should not be necessary.  If you create a whole new instance of a mock, it should not be carrying around previous expectations.  Funky.

Comment: I have same problem, is there any final solution to this?