# RhinoMocks: override a stubbed property

Tags: .net, rhino-mocks

Unfortunately the following pattern does not work in RhinoMocks:

```
[SetUp]
public void SetUp ()
{
    obj.Stub(s => s.Prop).Returns("a suitable default for all tests");
}

[Test]
public void VerySpecificTest ()
{
    obj.Stub(s => s.Prop).Returns("specific value, valid only for this single test");
}
```

It does not even throw an exception (which is particularly bad), the user just does not know why the second `Stub()` call does not have any effect whatsoever.

However, is there a way to make this work? How to "overwrite" a single property return?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIRC, the supported way to override a previously recorded behavior of a stub or mock is to fall back Rhino Mocks' older API: you can use `BackToRecord` to cause the stub to forget its previously recorded behavior, then use `Replay` to go back to playback mode, then stub the property again:

```
[SetUp]
public void SetUp ()
{
    obj.Stub(s => s.Prop).Returns("a suitable default for all tests");
}

[Test]
public void VerySpecificTest ()
{
    // Clear recorded expectations and immediately go back to replay mode.
    obj.BackToRecord();
    obj.Replay();

    // Now setup a new expectation.
    obj.Stub(s => s.Prop).Returns("specific value, valid only for this single test");
}
```

The drawback to this method is that `BackToRecord` causes the stub to forget all the expectations set up for it (not only the one you might want to override). There are a few hackarounds that avoid this (e.g., to use `Repeat`, or to set up the initial `Stub` using a lambda so that you can change the returned value later on; see e.g., [How to clear previous expectations on an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/770013/62838) for some of these), but there is no supported API for this.

Comment: Your explanation of `BackToRecord` sounds like all my Stub() calls are gone? So it's kinda like creating a new stub from scratch?

Comment: Yes, and it also changes the stub's behavior to behave like a strict mock, so ... not quite ideal.

Comment: This is a good answer to a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/770083/62838.

Comment: There is one more twist to it: when put the `Stub` call between `BackToRecord` and `Replay`, it switches the object to strict mode. When, however, you put the `Stub` call _after_ the `Replay`, it keeps the stub behavior. I'll adapt the code sample accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for all the information, I've found the other thread before as well, however, I thought there must be some easy/easier way to achieve this... :-)

Comment: I've edited the answer to contain all the additional details :)